# How does the DKIM from SendGrid prevent me from spoofing my email adress?

Tags: email, sendgrid, dkim

I'm making use of SendGrid to send automatic emails. First I went to the whole hassle of creating a DKIM record, before I recently discovered the whole record doesn't seem to be checked anyway, because SendGrid provides it's own DKIM record.

See: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/dkim.html

How does this work? If I don't need to provide my own DKIM for the domain I'm sending from, how does this prevent me from just spoofing the email adress from some domain I don't own?

Comment: This is a superuser.com (or serverfault.com? Not sure but I'd try SU first) question instead of here. That said http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail#Use_with_spam_filtering could be a good starting point.  You may get a better answer on one of those other sites.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand that DKIM is based on public key cryptography.  That means that a pair of keys is involved - a private key and a public key.

In this case, Sendgrid keeps possession of the private key, and provides you with the public key as a DNS TXT record to be published by you in DNS.

You MUST publish the public key as a DNS TXT record on the domain to be verified for DKIM to work.  By publishing the record in DNS, you confirm ownership of the domain.  Only someone who owns the domain can publish a DNS record, which means that only domain owners can authorize a private key to sign emails.

And only someone in possession of the private key - in this case, Sendgrid - can sign emails that will be DKIM verified for this domain.  No one else can sign emails that will verify against this particular key.

This is how DKIM works.